# Will I be getting older on my profile here automatically?

Tags: support

Will my "age" value be changing every year in my profile or I would have to change it  manually every my birthday?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The age field updates automatically based on the birthday you submit.

Comment: Aaaah! I understand now. Thank You.

Comment: But, but, what if you wanted to stay 39 forever?